# Wow! How did I lose 70 on this answer?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, merged-questions

[Why does #define not require a semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735099/why-does-define-not-require-a-semicolon/40460744#40460744)

It's not closed or deleted, but my reputation has just dropped by 70, attributed to this answer.

Is there something funky going on?

**Edit, I've just received the necromancer silver badge for this, which I think is in error.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That event wasn't caused by the merge as suggested. The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460701/why-cant-i-define-an-array-size-using-define-constant) was actually deleted, which caused your answer to be deleted along with it and you lost the reputation for the answer at that time. It was then undeleted and merged into a different question. This updates the parent question ID, which immediately changes the title associated with your answer.

**But** the system hasn't yet recalculated your reputation to remove the "removed" event due to the undeletion. It will eventually disappear and you'll regain the 80 reputation for the answer.

Comment: I'm being naughty here by editing my question, but I believe the awarding of the necromancer badge is a bug.

Comment: [Necromancer badge given based on merged duplicate instead of master question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166877/necromancer-badge-given-based-on-merged-duplicate-instead-of-master-question)

Answer (score 8):

The post was merged, which is technically implemented as the post being deleted and then re-created on the target question.  So you technically lost 70 reputation from having a post with 7 upvotes deleted, and then earned 70 reputation from having a new post with 7 upvotes created (for a net change of 0).

Comment: [For reference](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40460744/timeline#history_737128ab-0392-484f-b985-7e17b43cad24) see the timeline.